# Making my GUI accessible through keyboard (Xp, Visual Studio, C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, keyboard, accessibility

I've built a GUI with button, groups of buttons, edits, listboxes... etc... but now I want to know how to make my gui accessible through keyboard, I mean, changing the focus by pressing tab button. Does anybody have any idea on how to do this? I'm using Windows Xp and the GUI is writen on C++ using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks a lot

UPDATE:

```
INT APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ics;
    ics.dwSize = sizeof(ics);
    ics.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&ics);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_PRUEBA, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDA_ACCEL_TABLE));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if ((!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) && (!IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg))) 
        //if ((!IsDialogMessage(msg.hwnd, &msg)) & (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg) )) 
        //if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

I have a lot of controls in my GUI, should I put WS_TABSTOP in all of them? What if I have a group of buttons... should I put WS_TABSTOP in every button and in the group? only in the individual buttons?

For example I'll paste a group I've created:

```
INT CrearControles(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HFONT hfont;
    HWND hctrl;
    int i;

    hInstance = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
    hfont = (HFONT)GetStockObject( DEFAULT_GUI_FONT );

    /* Insertar controles */    
    hctrl = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        "BUTTON",        /* Nombre de la clase */
        "Rol",       /* Texto del título */
        BS_GROUPBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP , /* Estilo */
        20, 15,           /* Posición */
        180, 100,          /* Tamaño */
        hwnd,            /* Ventana padre */
        (HMENU)GRUPO_ROL,/* Identificador del control */
        hInstance,       /* Instancia */
        NULL);           /* Sin datos de creación de ventana */ 
    SendMessage(hctrl, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));

    hctrl = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Receptor", BS_NOTIFY | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 30, 35,
      70, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BOTON_RECEPTOR, hInstance, NULL);           
    SendMessage(hctrl, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, BOTON_RECEPTOR, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, 0);           
    SetFocus(hctrl);

    hctrl = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Emisor", BS_NOTIFY | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 30, 65,
      70, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)BOTON_EMISOR, hInstance, NULL);         
    SendMessage(hctrl, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));


    hctrl = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", "Telefono", SS_SIMPLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 150, 55, 100, 55, hwnd, (HMENU)LABEL_TELEFONO,
          hInstance, NULL);          
    SendMessage(hctrl, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
    SetFocus(hctrl); 

    hctrl = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", "", ES_READONLY | ES_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | ES_NUMBER , 115, 68,
          80, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)EDIT_TELEFONO, hInstance, NULL); 
    SendMessage(hctrl, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
    SetFocus(hctrl);       

    return 1;
}
```

Thx

Comment: Do those buttons exist in windows or in dialogs? How do you create them?

Comment: I create them on LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam). On WM_CREATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're GUI is running as a standard modal dialog you should get tabbing and Alt key navigation between controls for free.

ie: controls with the WS_TABSTOP style set you should be able to tab to, controls with short cut key defined (eg: a button with a caption of "&Do Something" should be accessible with Alt+D - and the D should be displayed underlined).

If your window is not running as standard modal dialog, to get this behaviour your message loop needs to call IsDialogMessage before dispatching each message.

eg:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(m_hWndYourWindow, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my GUI is not modal. I have a similar loop in my code but instead IsDialogMessage I've put if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) . The accelerators work this way, but where do I have to put IsDialogMessage to make tab key work. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use something like "if (!TranslateAccelerator(...) && !IsDialogMessage(...))"

Comment: When I do that the accelerators stop working, and neither do the tab button.

Comment: Are you saying that if you put in "if (!TransactionAccelerator)" you get accelerators working and if you put in "if (!IsDialogMessage))" you get tab key working, but you can't get both working together?

Also, make sure you have the WS_TABSTOP style set on the controls you want to tab to.

Also, try swapping the order of the calls to "if (!IsDialogMessage(...) && ! TranslateAccelerator(...))".  Perhaps one is precluding the other.

If you like, post the full code for your message loop and I'll take a look.

Comment: If I only put Translate accelerators work. If I only put IsDialogMessage tab doesn't work. If I put both of them (also if I swap the order) neither of them work. I'll post my code, but I think the problem could be on the controls... maybe I've created them wrongly.

Comment: I think the first parameter to IsDialogMessage is wrong - it should be the handle to the top level window - not the window handle of the message being dispatched.

Comment: Kudos 2 U! It was just like u said :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it normal that to use the accelerators I have to push alt first and then the letter (they aren't pushed simutaneously) ? It happens when I have IsDialogMessage in the if... if not it works ok (pushing them simoultaneously).

Comment: Hrm,  I can't think of any reason why using IsDialogMessage would conflict with TranslateAccelerator.  If they do I have no idea why and the only thing I can suggest is the same as before - try swapping the order of TranslateAccelerator/IsDialogMessage.  Sorry can't help on that one.